# Start a QProcess with PYTHONPATH set to different python version

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pythonpath, qprocess

I have created a PyQt app using python 3.3 and Qt4.8 and I am starting a QProcess from it. The newly started child process tries to run a python script and this script fails because it searches for python modules in 3.3 directory (default python on system is 2.7).

I think it is searching for python modules in python 3.3 directory because child process inherits its environment (and therefore PYTHONPATH) from parent process. I can change PYTHONPATH using QProcess.setProcessEnvironment but how do I get the value of PYTHONPATH for 2.7 within a PyQt app which is using python 3.3?

**EDIT:**
The answer below by Viktor worked for me. I needed to remove PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME from the environment. I needed to remove PYTHONHOME because otherwise launcher was being used from my app's local directory ( I created app/package using py2app ). Below is the code:

```
systemEnvironment = QtCore.QProcessEnvironment.systemEnvironment()
systemEnvironment.remove( 'PYTHONPATH' )
systemEnvironment.remove( 'PYTHONHOME' )
process.setProcessEnvironment( systemEnvironment )
```

Comment: Add problematic part of the code you have to the question.

Comment: process = QProcess(self);
process.start("perl abc.pl");

This abc.pl in trun invokes another python scripts and I need to invoke it with PYTHONPATH set to search 2.7 environment (current script is running in python 3.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Get the current environment end filter out the old
# PYTHONPATH variable if exists in the environment
env = [env for env in QtCore.QProcess.systemEnvironment()
       if not env.startswith('PYTHONPATH=')]
# Add your PYTHONPATH
env.append('PYTHONPATH=path_to_where_you_want')
# Create a process, set the environment and run the script
p = QtCore.QProcess()
p.setEnvironment(env)
p.start('perl abc.pl')
```

If you want the subprocess python to just revert to it's default `PYTHONPATH` just remove the current one from environment (skip the `env.append` part)

Comment: How do I find path to default python environment ( the one I get using sys.path in python interpreter from terminal ).

Comment: You just have to remove the PYTHONPATH from the environment variables and Python will fallback to it's default one.

Comment: I am also using  QtGui.QDesktopServices.openUrl( QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(path) ). Is there a way to edit environment for the newly started program by this call?

Comment: @Gaurav I think there isn't. At least I don't see it in the API documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Viktor. It proved really helpful :). Now I am using QProcess instead of QDesktopServices.